# How to fix this API error

Tags: apt, ubuntu-sdk, ubuntu-one-api

```
Checking API: checkpublicapi-last
Checking API: checkpublicapi-current
Checking API: checksystemapi-last
Checking API: checksystemapi-current
out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/public_api.txt:1966: error 17: Field android.R.style.TextAppearance_Material_Widget_Button_Inverse has changed value from 16974548 to 16974565
out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/public_api.txt:2011: error 17: Field android.R.style.ThemeOverlay_Material_Dialog has changed value from 16974550 to 16974564
out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/public_api.txt:2012: error 17: Field android.R.style.ThemeOverlay_Material_Dialog_Alert has changed value from 16974551 to 16974566
out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/public_api.txt:2120: error 17: Field android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_LightStatusBar has changed value from 16974549 to 16974563

******************************
You have tried to change the API from what has been previously released in
an SDK.  Please fix the errors listed above.
******************************


build/core/tasks/apicheck.mk:46: recipe for target 'out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/checkpublicapi-last-timestamp' failed
make: *** [out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/checkpublicapi-last-timestamp] Error 38
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/system-api.txt:2064: error 17: Field android.R.style.TextAppearance_Material_Widget_Button_Inverse has changed value from 16974548 to 16974565
out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/system-api.txt:2109: error 17: Field android.R.style.ThemeOverlay_Material_Dialog has changed value from 16974550 to 16974564
out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/system-api.txt:2110: error 17: Field android.R.style.ThemeOverlay_Material_Dialog_Alert has changed value from 16974551 to 16974566
out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/system-api.txt:2219: error 17: Field android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_LightStatusBar has changed value from 16974549 to 16974563

******************************
You have tried to change the API from what has been previously released in
an SDK.  Please fix the errors listed above.
******************************


build/core/tasks/apicheck.mk:92: recipe for target 'out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/checksystemapi-last-timestamp' failed
make: *** [out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/checksystemapi-last-timestamp] Error 38
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
make update-api && make -j4
```

from 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622020/couldnt-parse-api-file-frameworks-base-api-current-txt

-j depends on your processor count.